# How to convert string with hex characters into readable form in php

Tags: php

I have a string that contains hex characters.

**Example:**
"https:\x2F\x2Fhelp.site.com\x2Fdata\x2Fprivacy"

Is there any PHP function that can decode this kind of string?

Comment: Are they literal `\x` or actual `\xnn` characters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an build-in function you can use urldecode.

```
echo urldecode("https:\x2F\x2Fhelp.site.com\x2Fdata\x2Fprivacy");
// prints: https://help.site.com/data/privacy
```

Comment: im gonna use it in a big json file contains string with hex codes

Comment: You can load the JSON file into a variable and pass the variable into the function.

Comment: try `echo "https:\x2F\x2Fhelp.site.com\x2Fdata\x2Fprivacy";`

Comment: @Nick, you are right, the output is the same if you echo it directly. If you want to really convert it though and save it in a converted form you would need to pass it through a decoder.

Comment: Did you assign it to a variable? What are you doing with the decoded text?